# Download videos from TVE (Spanish TV site) using python

Tags: python, html, video, download, request

I would like to download videos from TVE (Spanish TV site) using python in order to make a database for sign language. [Example](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/telediario/telediario-8-horas-22-11-19-lengua-signos/5450714/):

As there is a huge amount of videos I'm trying to do so using python.

The fact is I have no idea about neither web programming or HTML. I tried to inspect the website to find a link to the raw video but I think it doesn't work that way. The most similar thing I found is this [link](https://secure-embed.rtve.es/drmn/embed/video/5450714) 
which I tried to download with this code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

'''
URL of the archive web-page which provides link to
all video lectures. It would have been tiring to
download each video manually.
In this example, we first crawl the webpage to extract
all the links and then download videos.
'''



def download_video_series(link):


    '''iterate through all links in video_links
    and download them one by one'''

    # obtain filename by splitting url and getting
    # last string
    file_name = link.split('/')[-1]+'.mp4'

    print
    "Downloading file:%s" % file_name

    # create response object
    r = requests.get(link, stream=True)

    # download started
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

    print(        "%s downloaded!\n" % file_name)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    # getting all video links

    # download all videos
    download_video_series('https://secure-embed.rtve.es/drmn/embed/video/5450714')
```

I also tried to use `wget` but it doesn't catch video rather than `text/html`

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure you have the rights to download and modify the content - even if it is broadcast free to air and unencrypted, the content owner may not allow it be modified and reused.

Assuming you do have the tights, then the broadcast you linked to uses HLS to stream the videos. HLS is a streaming protocol that breaks a video into multiple chunks and typically provides different resolutions for each chunk to allow best quality for a given device and for given network conditions.

Building a tool to download and reconstruct a video from a live HLS stream is probably not something you are going to want to tackle given you say you are a novice in this area, so you will mostly likely want to use an existing tool to do this.

There are many available if you search for 'download HLS video' - one example:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stream-recorder-download/iogidnfllpdhagebkblkgbfijkbkjdmm?hl=en